# Why are these settings unregistered?

Tags: settings-api

After updating a WordPress site to version 4.2 (and the forced 4.2.1 security update), I get some weird deprecated errors:

> Functionality: Unregistered Setting
>
> The `post-type-menu-page` setting is unregistered. Unregistered
>   settings are deprecated. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API
>   Deprecated in version 2.7.

I have the same error for lots of other post types: `post-type-dashboard-page`, `post-type-menu-post`, `post-type-menu-forum` (this is from bbPress), `post-type-dashboard-post` and more.

These errors have been reported by the Log Deprecated Calls plugin. There is no line or file shown.

Why do I get these errors?

I don't care about the native WordPress post types, I just want to fix my own post types to be up to date with 4.2+.

**EDIT:** Based on the option's structure, I couldn't find any reference both to `post-type-` or `post-type-menu-` in WordPress' source code.

Comment: We'll need to see the code that registers or adds the `post-type-menu-page`, we're not psychic :)

Comment: I understand, I suppose that's WordPress core code. I'll try to dig it up.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually misleading here. WP isn't checking if the settings are registered -- e.g., `if ( isset( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_settings']['foo'] ) )` -- it's checking if the form was posted to the default options page (`options.php`), rather than a custom one (`options-general.php?page=foo`).

So, it's entirely possible to get this warning after calling `register_setting()`, if you're doing something like this:

`<form method="post" action="options.php">`

You can just remove the entire `action` attribute, since it'll post to the current URL by default. In that case, it'll include the `?page=foo` parameter, so `$unregistered` won't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Given that "I just want to fix my own post types to be up to date with 4.2+", you need to register your settings with [`register_setting()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting)

The warning you are seeing is generated in [`wp-admin/options.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.1/src/wp-admin/options.php):

```
180         if ( $options ) {
181                 foreach ( $options as $option ) {
182                         if ( $unregistered )
183                                 _deprecated_argument( 'options.php', '2.7', sprintf( __( 'The <code>%1$s</code> setting is unregistered. Unregistered settings are deprecated. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API' ), $option, $option_page ) );
```

`$unregistered` is set earlier in the same file:

```
134 if ( 'update' == $action ) {
135         if ( 'options' == $option_page && !isset( $_POST['option_page'] ) ) { // This is for back compat and will eventually be removed.
136                 $unregistered = true;
137                 check_admin_referer( 'update-options' );
138         } else {
139                 $unregistered = false;
140                 check_admin_referer( $option_page . '-options' );
141         }
```